# Can a scalar-valued function or a vector-valued function ever not be a real-valued function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, real-numbers

A real-valued function has to output a real number or a vector that is composed only of real numbers.

But can a scalar-valued function or vector-valued function output an imaginary number if it is not also labeled as real-valued?

For example, is this a scalar valued function?

$$
f:x \mapsto x\sqrt{-1}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general truth in mathematics is that functions do ***not*** exist independently from their domain and codomain. This is a misconception generated by those pre-calc problems where they asked you to "find the domain" of a certain formula. So $f$ by itself (the "mapping rule") is *not* a function; $f : A \to B$, instead, *is*. Therefore, you *need* to specify what $A$ and $B$ are when defining a function.

Real numbers live in $\mathbb R$. Real euclidean vectors live in $\mathbb R^n$ for some $n$. A function from $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is called *real(-valued) function of one real variable*. A function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ is called *vector(-valued) function of one real variable*. A function $f : \mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R$ is called a *real(-valued) function of $k$ real variables*. Just guess what functions like $f : \mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R^n$ are.

In the context of real vector spaces, and in particular $\mathbb R^n$, *scalars* are the elements of the base field of the vector space. In the case of $\mathbb R^n$, that field is most naturally $\mathbb R$. So any time you find "*real(-valued)*" in the above nomenclatures, you may substitute *scalar(-valued)*.

As you know, the imaginary unit $i$ is not in $\mathbb R$, so the function you proposed (wherever your $x$ comes from) may *never* be of the kinds listed above. However, if $x$ came from $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb C^n$, the map $x \mapsto ix$ would not be such a strange sight.

Comment: That's a very helpful answer, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

*Scalar* means *with values in the base field*, whatever that field is. It depends on the context. The terminology is derived from the fact that when you multiply a set of vectors by a number, you *scale* the picture (you change the scale but not the overall shape). Hence numbers are "scalers".

When geometry and linear algebra get axiomatised, and you start working over an arbitrary vector/affine space over some base field, scalars are elements of the field. In particular, it could very well be the field of complex numbers.